# "there were errors during the upgrade" - how to proceed?

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, upgrade

I have just upgraded my Ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04, and got the following message:

```
The upgrade has completed but there were errors during the upgrade process. 

To continue please press [ENTER]
```

There was no further information regarding the errors. After pressing ENTER, I did:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt do-release-upgrade
```

and there were no errors, and I got the message:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS develoment release 
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.
```

I am worried about this "there were errors during the upgrade process" message, since I read that after an upgrade, there may be a problem after reboot - the desktop might not show up. How can I check what errors happened during the upgrade, and how to fix them?

Comment: There may be some log files still in `/var/log/apt/`. Look at `term.log` or earlier versions.

Comment: Indeed there is a file term.log there, but I did not find any errors - only two warnings: "insserv: warning: script 'K01lampp' missing LSB tags and overrides" and "insserv: warning: script 'lampp' missing LSB tags and overrides"..

Comment: Did you check the dates? Are these warnings from around the time you ran the upgrade?

Comment: @Jos yes,  they are from now

Comment: In that case, I wouldn't worry too much. These are warnings that you can safely ignore, but they were probably the reason that the upgrade reports that there were errors. More important is that your packages are complete and consistent. I think you can safely reboot.